# DI values in table

Tags: pine-script

## Introduction

I'd like to display the DI values for 5 securities in a table.

Here's an existing DI indicator that I'm basing my code on:

[ADX and DI for v4](https://www.tradingview.com/script/VTPMMOrx-ADX-and-DI/)

## Code

Here's what I have so far.

```
//@version=5
indicator("table-di-plus", overlay = true)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
type result
    float close_
    float high_
    float low_
    float DIPlus
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// parameters
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
len = input(14)
th = input(20)    
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
sym1 = input.symbol('PG',   'Symbol 1')
sym2 = input.symbol('MMM',  'Symbol 2')
sym3 = input.symbol('CYBR', 'Symbol 3')
sym4 = input.symbol('QCOM', 'Symbol 4')
sym5 = input.symbol('FTNT', 'Symbol 5')

obj1 = result.new()
obj2 = result.new()
obj3 = result.new()
obj4 = result.new()
obj5 = result.new()

obj1.close_ := request.security(sym1, '', close)
obj2.close_ := request.security(sym2, '', close)
obj3.close_ := request.security(sym3, '', close)
obj4.close_ := request.security(sym4, '', close)
obj5.close_ := request.security(sym5, '', close)

obj1.high_ := request.security(sym1, '', high)
obj2.high_ := request.security(sym2, '', high)
obj3.high_ := request.security(sym3, '', high)
obj4.high_ := request.security(sym4, '', high)
obj5.high_ := request.security(sym5, '', high)

obj1.high_ := request.security(sym1, '', low)
obj2.high_ := request.security(sym2, '', low)
obj3.high_ := request.security(sym3, '', low)
obj4.high_ := request.security(sym4, '', low)
obj5.high_ := request.security(sym5, '', low)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

calc(result obj) =>

    close_ = obj.close_
    high_ = obj.high_
    low_ = obj.low_

    TrueRange = math.max(math.max(high_-low_, math.abs(high_-nz(close_[1]))), math.abs(low_-nz(close_[1])))
    DirectionalMovementPlus = high_-nz(high_[1]) > nz(low_[1])-low_ ? math.max(high_-nz(high_[1]), 0): 0
    DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low_[1])-low_ > high_-nz(high_[1]) ? math.max(nz(low_[1])-low_, 0): 0

    SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
    SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange

    SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = 0.0
    SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementPlus

    SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = 0.0
    SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementMinus

    DIPlus  = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus  / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
    DIMinus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100

    obj.DIPlus := DIPlus
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
calc(obj1)
calc(obj2)
calc(obj3)
calc(obj4)
calc(obj5)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
var table tbl = table.new(
     position = position.top_right, 
     columns = 20, 
     rows = 10, 
     bgcolor = color.white, 
     frame_color = color.black, 
     frame_width = 2, 
     border_color = color.black, 
     border_width = 2)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
tbl.cell(0, 1, sym1)
tbl.cell(0, 2, sym2)
tbl.cell(0, 3, sym3)
tbl.cell(0, 4, sym4)
tbl.cell(0, 5, sym5)

tbl.cell(1, 1, str.tostring(obj1.DIPlus))
tbl.cell(1, 2, str.tostring(obj2.DIPlus))
tbl.cell(1, 3, str.tostring(obj3.DIPlus))
tbl.cell(1, 4, str.tostring(obj4.DIPlus))
tbl.cell(1, 5, str.tostring(obj5.DIPlus))
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

## Approach

The `DI` code uses `close`, `high`, `low`. So for each security, let's keep these in an object:

```
type result
    float close_
    float high_
    float low_
    float DIPlus
```

Let's load the securities and create objects for each one:

```
sym1 = input.symbol('PG',   'Symbol 1')
sym2 = input.symbol('MMM',  'Symbol 2')
sym3 = input.symbol('CYBR', 'Symbol 3')
sym4 = input.symbol('QCOM', 'Symbol 4')
sym5 = input.symbol('FTNT', 'Symbol 5')

obj1 = result.new()
obj2 = result.new()
obj3 = result.new()
obj4 = result.new()
obj5 = result.new()

obj1.close_ := request.security(sym1, '', close)
obj2.close_ := request.security(sym2, '', close)
obj3.close_ := request.security(sym3, '', close)
obj4.close_ := request.security(sym4, '', close)
obj5.close_ := request.security(sym5, '', close)

obj1.high_ := request.security(sym1, '', high)
obj2.high_ := request.security(sym2, '', high)
obj3.high_ := request.security(sym3, '', high)
obj4.high_ := request.security(sym4, '', high)
obj5.high_ := request.security(sym5, '', high)

obj1.high_ := request.security(sym1, '', low)
obj2.high_ := request.security(sym2, '', low)
obj3.high_ := request.security(sym3, '', low)
obj4.high_ := request.security(sym4, '', low)
obj5.high_ := request.security(sym5, '', low)
```

I have a `calc` function that takes care of computing `DIPlus` for each object. This is where I've converted the original DI indicator code over to my version. I've also changed a few items to make it work with V5. It was originally for V4.

```
calc(result obj) =>

    close_ = obj.close_
    high_ = obj.high_
    low_ = obj.low_

    TrueRange = math.max(math.max(high_-low_, math.abs(high_-nz(close_[1]))), math.abs(low_-nz(close_[1])))
    DirectionalMovementPlus = high_-nz(high_[1]) > nz(low_[1])-low_ ? math.max(high_-nz(high_[1]), 0): 0
    DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low_[1])-low_ > high_-nz(high_[1]) ? math.max(nz(low_[1])-low_, 0): 0

    SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
    SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange

    SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = 0.0
    SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementPlus

    SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = 0.0
    SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementMinus

    DIPlus  = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus  / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
    DIMinus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100

    obj.DIPlus := DIPlus
```

## Result

The table appears with the security names, however, the `DIPlus` values show up as `NaN`:

[image]

## Question

What's a good way to get the table to display the actual `DIPlus` values instead of `NaN`?

As you can see, the idea here is to generalize a typical indicator to a few securities in a table.

## Update 1 : screener function

Looking at other questions on here involving screeners, I see that one technique is to use a "screener function" and to use this with the `request.security` function.

Here's a version which takes this approach instead:

```
//@version=5
indicator("table-di-plus", overlay = true)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
// parameters
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
len = input(14)
th = input(20)    
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
di_screener_function() =>
    
    TrueRange = math.max(math.max(high-low, math.abs(high-nz(close[1]))), math.abs(low-nz(close[1])))
    DirectionalMovementPlus = high-nz(high[1]) > nz(low[1])-low ? math.max(high-nz(high[1]), 0): 0
    DirectionalMovementMinus = nz(low[1])-low > high-nz(high[1]) ? math.max(nz(low[1])-low, 0): 0

    SmoothedTrueRange = 0.0
    SmoothedTrueRange := nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1]) - (nz(SmoothedTrueRange[1])/len) + TrueRange

    SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus = 0.0
    SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementPlus

    SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus = 0.0
    SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus := nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1]) - (nz(SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus[1])/len) + DirectionalMovementMinus

    DIPlus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementPlus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100
    DIMinus = SmoothedDirectionalMovementMinus / SmoothedTrueRange * 100

    [DIPlus, DIMinus]
    
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
sym1 = input.symbol('PG',   'Symbol 1')
sym2 = input.symbol('MMM',  'Symbol 2')
sym3 = input.symbol('CYBR', 'Symbol 3')
sym4 = input.symbol('QCOM', 'Symbol 4')
sym5 = input.symbol('FTNT', 'Symbol 5')

[sym1_DIPlus, sym1_DIMinus] = request.security(sym1, '', di_screener_function())
[sym2_DIPlus, sym2_DIMinus] = request.security(sym2, '', di_screener_function())
[sym3_DIPlus, sym3_DIMinus] = request.security(sym3, '', di_screener_function())
[sym4_DIPlus, sym4_DIMinus] = request.security(sym4, '', di_screener_function())
[sym5_DIPlus, sym5_DIMinus] = request.security(sym5, '', di_screener_function())
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
var table tbl = table.new(
     position = position.top_right, 
     columns = 20, 
     rows = 10, 
     bgcolor = color.white, 
     frame_color = color.black, 
     frame_width = 2, 
     border_color = color.black, 
     border_width = 2)
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
tbl.cell(0, 1, sym1)
tbl.cell(0, 2, sym2)
tbl.cell(0, 3, sym3)
tbl.cell(0, 4, sym4)
tbl.cell(0, 5, sym5)

tbl.cell(1, 1, str.tostring(sym1_DIPlus))
tbl.cell(1, 2, str.tostring(sym2_DIPlus))
tbl.cell(1, 3, str.tostring(sym3_DIPlus))
tbl.cell(1, 4, str.tostring(sym4_DIPlus))
tbl.cell(1, 5, str.tostring(sym5_DIPlus))
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This version appears to work!

[image]

Comment: I suggest an optimization feature. When you want to draw Tables, usually you want to do it on the last bar, either because you were collecting data throughout the entire bar Series or you want to display some information regarding the last bar (or the previous few). Both cases you need to draw the Table at the last bar, and skip it during the rest of the bars. Put the entire table drawing part into an IF block using `if barstate.islast`. The Table definition should remain outside the IF block.

Comment: Yup, good suggestion. Started doing that recently. Thank you!